# Casting an object to a custom class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, casting

I'm developing a HTML 5 application.

In Javascript I have defined a custom class and a HashTable implementation:

```
function Card(newId, newName, newDescription)
{
    this.id = newId;
    this.name = newName;
    this.description = newDescription;
}

function HashTable()
{
    var hashTableItems = {};

    this.SetItem = function(key, value)
    {
        hashTableItems[key] = value;
    }

    this.GetItem = function(key)
    {
        return hashTableItems[key];
    }
}
```

I use HashTable to add Card's objects. I use this code to add cards:

```
...
var card = new Card(id, name, description);

$.viacognitaspace.cards.SetItem(id, card);
...
```

My problem is when I call HashTable.GetItem and I don't know how to cast object returned to Card class.

```
var cardObject = $.viacognitaspace.cards.GetItem(cardNumber);
```

Here, `cardObject` is undefined.

If I do this:

```
$('#cardName').text(cardObject.name);
```

I get an error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: We need to see the rest of the code.  Do you add something at card number location -- that would seem the problem to me.

Comment: `cardObject` being undefined means it's not in the hashtable, but that has nothing to do with casting. If you only "set" Card objects, you'll only "get" Card objects (or undefined)

Comment: I've updated my question. Now, you can see how I add a Card object to HastTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying your code to the following:

```
$.viacognitaspace = {} /* define namespace if not already defined... */

var card = new Card(id, name, description);

/* the "new" keyword creats an instance of your HashTable function
   which allows you to reference and modify it later on... */
$.viacognitaspace.cards = new HashTable();

$.viacognitaspace.cards.SetItem(id, card);
```

You also need to create an instance of the `HashTable function`.

***Example:***

http://jsfiddle.net/3BWpM/